# puppet tomcat6 service does not receive environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, tomcat6, puppet

I am using Debian OS and tomcat6.

I export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m" environment variable and create a puppet service:

```
class tomcat6::service { 
    service { 'tomcat6':
        ensure => running,
        hasstatus => true,
        hasrestart => true,
        enable => true,
    }
}
```

As /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh reads CATALINA_OPTS variables for starting tomcat6 service, the process should receive CATALINA_OPTS but it does not show in the process command. I execute `ps aux|grep catalina` to show the command detail:

```
tomcat6  10658  1.0  2.0 2050044 189572 ?      Sl   18:04   0:16 /usr/lib/jvm/default-        java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat6-tomcat6-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Puppet does not receive CATALINA_OPTS properly.

My question is, how can I let puppet read CATALINA_OPTS when executing puppet tomcat6 service?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
hasstatus => true,
```

put

```
hasstatus => false,
```

By doing this, you will force puppet to look up the proc table and find the daemon OR in other words, this will make puppet run  `ps auxw | grep tomcat6` before doing anything else.

`hasstatus => true` tells that if puppet receives a `status != running` it will do as directed, but in some cases several daemons don't return the status correctly (probably due to mutiple threading involved)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Sorry I don't quite understand how it solves the issue after changing hasstatus to false. 

I expect CATALINA_OPTS will be included the proc command but it doesn't. hasstatus => false doesn't solve the issue. May you provide more detailed info? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by setting setenv.sh for tomcat6. It works properly.